# Can't install pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I downloaded pycharm from JetBrains website.
After running the .exe file, a message pops stating " This installation contains JetsBrains runtime 11 which does not support Microsoft Windows 32-bit version," .
What should I do to install pycharm on my machine.

Comment: Which version of Windows are you running? Is it a 32 or 64 bit installation? Please add additional information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

only releases before 2018-3-7 contain 32-bit.Or upgrade your operation system to 64 bit